# The appropriate prepositions?

Tags: grammar

Why we use "in" in: I worked in the mailroom.

While we use "at" and "in"
in:

I worked in a place.
I worked at a [image]place.

Answer (score 1):

The mail room is a room, like a bathroom or a bedroom: you can only be **in** it, you can't be **at** it.

For a place, you can definitely be **at** a place. 'place' can be used colloquially for an institution of some kind, and so **in** can also be used.
I think that "**at** a place" is the more common usage, though.

Answer (score 0):

The word place is non-specific, so "in" or "at" could be used.  Since a mailroom is specifically a "room", which implies an indoor space, "in" is the correct usage.  That said, you could use the word "at" with mailroom and some dialects of English do, but the more common usage is "in".